# Drain GCP dataflow jobs with terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataflow

When deploying a dataflow job with terraform it does not drain the old job.
Is there a possibility to automatically drain it and the deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not the responsability of `Terraform` to deploy custom `Dataflow` jobs (not `Dataflow` templates).

It's more the responsability of the deployment task proposed by a `CI CD` pipeline.

In this case there is no possibility to automatically drain and deploy a new version of the job.

You have to develop your own script (`Shell` for example) to do that and apply your strategy.

For example, a `Dataflow` job can be [drained](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/stopping-a-pipeline#stop_a_job) by a `gcloud` command :

```bash
gcloud dataflow jobs drain JOB_ID
```